# Delete a record gave me NotFoundException in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5, routes

How can I create multiple requests for the same route like below.

Route.php

```
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');//->middleware('auth');
Route::get('/home/{$user}','HomeController@showStudent');
Route::delete('/home/{$studentId}','HomeController@deleteStudent');
```

the form was working fine until I have added the delete request. In my blade template I have code something like this.

home.blade.php

```
  <form class="" role="form" method="DELETE" action="/home/{{$student->id}}">
                            {{ csrf_field() }}
                            <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Remove Student</button></td>
                            </form>
```

I believe because of the same routes it's showing NotFoundHTTPException.

On one route /home I am trying to Add, Show, Edit and Delete a record with different buttons.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a form and use Laravel's Form Method Spoofing

```
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
```

See more here...http://laravel.com/docs/master/routing#form-method-spoofing

Try as below....

```
 <form class="" role="form" method="DELETE" action="/home/{{$student->id}}">
 <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">           
 <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Remove Student</button></td>
 </form>
```

Comment: I have tried it but no luck with it. It still showing me the same not found exception.

Comment: you `resource controller`..https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/controllers#resource-controllers` for CRUD operations...no need to specify `routes` for each operations..

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have removed all my Home Controller paths and Added

Comment: @vsoni welcome and enjoy..if answer is useful plz accept it.Thank you.

Comment: I have added Route::resource('home','HomeController'); in my route file.

Comment: Yes,you are doing best..for `CRUD` operations always use `resource controller`.

Answer (score 0):

1) Change you route from:

```
Route::delete('/home/{$studentId}','HomeController@deleteStudent');
```

To:

```
Route::get('/delete/{$Id}','HomeController@deleteStudent')->name('delete');
```

2) change you form tag from:

```
<form class="" role="form" method="DELETE" action="/home/{{$student->id}}">
```

To:

```
<form class="" role="form" method="get" action="route('delete', ['id' => $student->id])">
```

Answer (score -1):

HTML forms doesn't support methods other than `get` and `post`. If you need to simulate it, include a hidden input to simulate `delete`:

```
<input name="_method" type="hidden" value="DELETE">
```

Then in your code, update it to:

```
<form class="" role="form" method="POST" action="/home/{{$student->id}}">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="DELETE">
    <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Remove Student</button></td>
</form>
```

Reference:

- [Are the PUT, DELETE, HEAD, etc methods available in most web browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/165779/are-the-put-delete-head-etc-methods-available-in-most-web-browsers)
- http://laraveldaily.com/theres-no-putpatchdelete-method-or-how-to-build-a-laravel-form-manually/

Comment: he is going to delete but...you just copy from laravel site `<input name="_method" type="hidden" value="PUT">`.wrong answer.

Comment: Wow.. like that to receive a demotion.. you guys are cruel and never give us a chance..